# How to get javascript response in Angular promise

Tags: javascript, angular

I am calling a javascript function in an angular component. I included the JS file in " angular.json " and it works fine.
The JS function do a http GET request and return data. The problem is I couldn't tell Angular to wait for the JS response to then fetch data.

This is my JS function :

```
function getDataJsFunct(id) {
   var params = {id:id}
   apiClient.getById(params) { console.log('data from JS', result); 
      return result;
   }
}
```

And this is my TS files : 
In api-services.ts

```
declare var getDataJsFunct: any;

export class ApiServices {
.
.
   public getAction(id) {
    return new Promise ( resolve => {
      const data = getDataJsFunct(id);
      if (data) {
        console.log('result', data);
        return resolve();
      }

    });
  }
}
```

In component.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {
  constructor(private serviceProvider: ApiServices) {}
  getDataFromProvider(id) {
    return this.serviceProvider.getAction(id);
  }
}
```

In component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
  let id = '123456';
  this.componentService.getDataFromProvider(id).then((data: any) => {
     this.dataFromBd = data.Items[0];
  },
  error => {
     console.log('Error in getting Data', error);
  });
}
```

The program is crashing at " getDataFromProvider(id).`***then***`((data " because getDataFromProvided(id) is undefined.
I suppose that I need a promise to tell Angular to wait for JS response then continu executing. How and where should I do that please ?

Comment: You've tagged this `async-await` but those keywords are not present in your code. Also, I'm not sure this line of code does what you might think it does; `apiClient.getById(params) { console.log('data from JS', result);` The bracket there does nothing.

Comment: Thank you Heretic, I removed the Tag async-await, I added it because I thought that we can use it in this case. The console.log is just for showin the result from JS function and it works, so the problem is in Angular Level.

Comment: "and it works" From the code you've shown here, it should log `data from JS undefined` since `result` is not defined in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are not passing the correct variable name in the service.

Currently, you have:

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {
  constructor(private serviceProvider: ApiServices) {}
  getDataFromProvider(urlApi) {
    return this.serviceProvider.getAction(id);
  }
}
```

You are calling `this.serviceProvider.getAction(id)` with the variable `id` when the parameter of the function is `urlApi`.

You should change `urlApi` for `id`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {
  constructor(private serviceProvider: ApiServices) {}
  getDataFromProvider(id) {
    return this.serviceProvider.getAction(id);
  }
}
```

Can you check if that was the issue?

Comment: Hello @German no actually it was when posting the question I changed some variables ! I fixed it now but the problem isn't that. Thank you.

Comment: @Tanboula I am happy to know that you fix your issue. Please, answer your own question and mark it us close, in other your case can help someone with the same issue in the future :)

Comment: no I didn't fi the problem haha ! I mean that I corrected the question.